# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let's say I have series $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{1+n^2x^2}$ and want to find its convergence intervals. I use root test:

As $n \to \infty$

$S=\lim\sqrt[n]{\frac{nx^n}{1+n^2x^2}}=\lim\frac{\sqrt[n]{n}|x|}{\sqrt[n]{1+n^2x^2}}=\lim\frac{|x|}{\sqrt[n]{1+n^2x^2}}=|x|\lim\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+n^2x^2}}<1$, then

$|x|<\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}$, but I get stuck at this point.

I tried expanding denominator with Taylor expansion formula and got:
$\sqrt[n]{1+n^2x^2}=1+nx^2-1/2((n-1)n^2)x^4+1/6n^3(2 n^2-3 n+1)x^6+1/24(-6n^7+11n^6-6n^5+n^4)x^8+...$

Any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't using the root test properly - you need to determine what the limit of S is as n tends to infinity, and then check to see if the value is less than 1; you can't do this in the opposite order.

Comment: You need to take the *limit* of $S$ as $n\to\infty$ to apply the root test.

Answer (score 2):

While this series is not a power series, many of the same ideas apply.  Specifically, for $|x|>1$, the general term does not go to zero and for $|x|<1$, the general term is comparable to $nx^n$, whose behavior is known.  You can then check the behavior at the endpoints.

Comment: Thus: 
1) $|x|<1$, series converge absolutely;
2) $x=-1$, converge by Leibnitz's test
3) $x=1$ and $|x|>1$, diverge

Am I correct?

Comment: @atomoutside yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the comparison test for series, with (for any fixed $x$ and $n\geq N$ with $N$ ``big enough'')
$$
\frac{x^{n-2}}{2n} =\frac{nx^n}{2n^2x^2} \leq \frac{nx^n}{1+n^2x^2} \leq nx^n
$$
to conclude that the radius is $1$.